# Converting xml file into an xls file

Tags: java, xml, csv, xls

I wrote an xml file using the below codes, how to convert that file into xls or csv file?
I want to read an xml file and covert it into an xls file, is there a possible way to do that?

```
            // write the content into xml file
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));
            try {
                // Output to console for testing
                // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                transformer.transform(source, result);

            } catch (TransformerException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CreditBureau.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
                 System.out.println("File saved!");

        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CreditBureau.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreditBureau.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: They are different file formats and serve their own purpose. Unless, you parse the xml and know what do you want to have in xls or csv, you cannot do it. Be very specific while you question, otherwise you tend to get very generic answers which may not be useful to you.

Comment: This looks intresting but I would prefer a java code which will help me in converting xml to xls or csv.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert using online site ..
http://www.luxonsoftware.com/converter/xmltoexcel

or  http://xmlgrid.net/xmlToExcel.html

Comment: This looks intresting but I would prefer a java code which will help me in converting xml to xls or csv.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Apache POI project.
It's library which allow you to modify Microsoft documents.

http://poi.apache.org/